# ¿Porque me sale java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string?? en JAVA

Tags: java

tengo un problema, estoy haciendo un mini-programa de verificar dni y cuando pruebo que haya una letra en los números me sale un error y no el texto que tendría que salir. Si alguien me ayuda porfaa

```
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String lletres, nif;
        int x, dni;
        System.out.println("Escriba su NIF: ");
        nif = sc.nextLine();
        
        x = nif.length();
        dni = Integer.parseInt(nif.substring(0,8));      
        lletres = "TRWAGMYFPDXBNJZSQVHLCKE";
        
        if (x != 9 ){        
           System.out.println ("NIF incorrecte, ha introduït " + x + " caràcters.");
          
           if (!nif.substring(0,8).matches("[0-9]")); //esto es lo que me da error.
            else 
            System.out.println("NIF incorrecte. Error especificant els 8 dígits de la part numèrica.");     
          
          if(!lletres.contains(nif.substring(nif.length()-1).toUpperCase()))
           System.out.println("NIF incorrecte. Lletra no vàlida.");
        
          if (lletres.substring(dni%23, dni%23+1).equals(nif.substring(nif.length()-1).toUpperCase()))
           System.out.println ("NIF CORRECTE");
          else
           System.out.println ("NIF INCORRECTE"); 

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error se produce más arriba, en esta línea:

```
dni = Integer.parseInt(nif.substring(0,8));
```

Se debe verificar si la cadena contiene letras antes de llamar `parseInt()` para tomar las acciones necesarias, ya se volver a pedir el ingreso o terminar el programa:

```
// si el NIF contiene letras volver a pedirlo
while(!nif.substring(0,8).matches("^[0-9]+$")){
            System.out.println("NIF contiene letras, ingreselo de nuevo");
            nif = sc.nextLine();
            x = nif.length();
}

dni = Integer.parseInt(nif.substring(0,8));
```

Comment: Muchas gracias funciona a la perfección. 10/10